# Add new DIV and Phone Icon

Tags: search, html

I have 2 folds question:

1. How do I add a Div above the s4-titlerow. Lets call this NavBar. Should I add this to Masterpage because it needs to be on all the site collections for persistent navigation.
2. Also, how do I add a Phone book icon next the search box so when user inputs a name and click on the phone book icon it takes them to people search result

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? This information could be helpful with the creation of an answer.

Comment: SharePoint 2013 enterprise.

Comment: Are you adding this Div for navigational links? Because you can have navigational links at the top of all sites OOB. Site Settings > Under "Look and Feel" click Navigation > then set the "Global Navigation" settings as you wish. Global navigation displays above site page titles and links can be added or removed. As for the second request do you use the SharePoint Developer software? That would be the best way to go about adding that phone book icon I believe.